# How do I find the file that contains attr_accessor method?

Tags: ruby

I know that attr_accessor is defined inside the Module class, but I am trying to find the source file for the Module class and cant find it.  I recursively searched in my ruby dir for 'def attr_accessor' and got nothing?

Any idea where it could be?

Comment: For further reading, here is an account of someone went along a similar path as you:

http://ghouston.blogspot.com/2006/05/attraccessor-meta-programming.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Module#attr_accessor is implemented in C. You can see the method definition if you use Pry:

```
[2] pry(main)> show-method Module#attr_accessor

From: object.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 10
Owner: Module
Visibility: private

static VALUE
rb_mod_attr_accessor(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    rb_attr(klass, rb_to_id(argv[i]), TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
[3] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rubinius, it's in [`kernel/delta/module.rb`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L191-200):

```
def attr_accessor(*names)
  vis = Rubinius::VariableScope.of_sender.method_visibility

  names.each do |name|
    Rubinius.add_reader name, self, vis
    Rubinius.add_writer name, self, vis
  end

  return nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Module (and attr_accessor) is part of the C source of ruby. It's located at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L1796 in the source